# AHK parse through clipboard to find how many times a string occurs

Tags: autohotkey

I have a large amount of text in the clipboard. I'm wanting to have a variable that counts how many instances of a specific text (ex abc whatever) occurs. I plan on going through this text over 40 times looking for over 40 different strings. All I need is how to do it once, and I will assign the variable and set it up for the rest following the same code.

Comment: Nothing so far, I wasn't sure what the base of the code would be. I know it would be either like a loop field or parse but I'm unsure how to set it up effectively as I didn't see any commands that seemed at a glance able to. By that I mean I looked over the command list just not sure which would be the most efficient. The string will be something like "abc whatever" so it needs to be able to recognize spaces and leave the space in place. I was figuring on matching the case with varfound+=1 but I'm unsure how to get it to go through all of the text.

Comment: Find something that works before you worry about most efficient. If it doesn't run quickly enough, you can then add that code to your question, and someone will help with that. There isn't really enough here to answer your question though. You are likely to get several responses all different based on someone elses ideas of what you are looking for. Here is a link to something similar: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/65828-help-parsing-text-on-clipboard/

Answer (score 0):

Best to write your own small function to count and then call that
with all terms.

Fill clipboard for example

```
clipboard :="blah E lba lbls blah e BLAH"
```

Code

```
msgbox, % howoftenis(clipboard,"blah E")
return

howoftenis(Haystack,Needle)
{
  count = 0
  pos = 0
  Loop,
  {
    StringGetPos, pos, Haystack, %Needle%,, %pos%    
    If (Errorlevel<>0)
      break
    count += 1
    pos +=1
  }    
  return count
}
```